# How to assign integer from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios4, nsarray, iphone

I would like to assign NSInteger by using NSMutableArray is there any way to solve this?
It is not working on simulator and cut off when run the application.

```
NSInteger Section;
NSMutableArray dataSourceSection;

Section = (NSInteger)[dataSourceSection objectAtIndex:2];
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have to put the integer in a NSNumber Object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `NSMutableArray` only stores objects. `NSInteger` is not an object, but a primitive data type. There is a class `NSNumber`, however, that can be used instead to store numeric values inside objects. Here's one example.

```
NSNumber *five = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:5];
NSMutableArray *numbers = [NSMutableArray array];
[numbers addObject:five];
```

To get the object back and retrieve the integer value use,

```
NSNumber *firstNumber = [numbers objectAtIndex:0];
NSInteger valueOfFirstNumber = [firstNumber integerValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't pull an NSInteger out of an NSMutableArray, basically because you can't put anything rather than objects in. in your case NSNumber would be the way to put numbers in NSMutablearray. if you do so you can easily get hold of your object, which is an NSNumber, and convert it to a NSInteger by:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// populate the array with NSNumbers
NSInteger number = [[array objectAtIndex:2] intValue];
```

Comment: right, sorry mate just edited the code it should be "intValue" instead of "integerValue". are you allocating and initializing the array?